# In 2023, does Texas require an air-gap between dishwasher and an in-sink food-waste 'disposerator'?

Tags: dishwasher, garbage-disposal, texas

I'm about to replace a leaking kitchen faucet (a $100 plastic Moedel from a big-box store) with a presumably higher Kuality faucet.  While doing this, I thought I'd look to see if my kitchen plumbing is up to code.

In particular, I was wanting to learn if Texas now requires the use of an air-gap between the dishwasher outlet, and the in-sink "disposerator".

Via google, I found [802.1.6 Domestic Dishwashing Machines](https://up.codes/viewer/texas/ipc-2015/chapter/8/indirect-special-waste#802.1.6), which says:

> Domestic dishwashing machines shall discharge indirectly through an air gap or air break into a waste receptor in accordance with Section 802.2, or discharge into a wye branch fitting on the tailpiece of the kitchen sink or the dishwasher connection of a food waste disposer. ***The waste line of a domestic dishwashing machine discharging into a*** kitchen sink tailpiece or ***food waste disposer shall connect to a deck-mounted air gap or the waste line shall rise and be securely fastened to the underside of the sink rim or counter.***

The parts I have ***emphasized*** seem to imply that I can keep on truckin' with my existing high-loop, or opt to switch to an air gap.

1. But that URL implies 2015, and so I can't really know if it is current.  Is it?
2. Bonus question:  in the specific residential application of a DW wasting into the side port of a disposerator, which of those two options (air-gap, or high-loop) are considered to be superior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Texas code has changed. These parts of codes generally don't change very often. If anything, I suspect that older code (possibly from a few decades older) had "only traditional air gap" and at some point it changed to "traditional air gap *or* high loop".

I prefer high loop, but each type has advantages and disadvantages:

- Traditional Air Gap

Advantages: Foolproof. If installed properly originally, then unless something actually breaks, the air gap will always be there.

Disadvantages: Requires a hole in the surface of the sink or counter. If something does break then you can have quite a mess.

- High Hose Loop

Advantages: Hidden. Simple - it is just a hose.

Disadvantages: If it is not installed properly, you might not realize it until there is a problem. If it is installed properly but comes loose, you might not realize it until there is a problem.

There is *general* rule with codes (electrical, plumbing, building, etc.) that if your installation was code-compliant originally then as long as you make no substantive changes you can continue using it even though newer code would require changes. Classic example is 3-wire vs. 4-wire dryer receptacles. But also GFCI and AFCI requirements and many other things. (I am more familiar with electrical than plumbing.) Otherwise you would constantly be upgrading your house when code changes, and nobody does that.

Replace an existing dishwasher and nothing has to be changed. But install a *second* dishwasher and that one will need to meet any updated code requirements.

But you know what a high loop is and how to install it properly. Continue to use it and don't worry.

Comment: "I suspect that older code (possibly from a few decades older) had only traditional air gap" -- I found older Texas plumbing code from 2000 (when my house was built)  that didn't even have that quoted 802.1.6 paragraph.
https://archive.org/details/gov.tx.plumbing/page/n73/mode/2up